# The play button in my android studio is disabled and I am not able to run the code on android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

The run button in my android studio is disabled and I am not able to run my flutter app on the virtual device.

I don't know what the issue might be as I have tried checking out some of the possible errors online.

I have also set the configuration to use the flutter project and the android folder in it as I saw in one of the solutions someone applied but still didn't work for me.

I ensured that I have the `sdk` configured, I have two current working `avd`.

These are some images I think could help as well.

[image: This is the virtual device that came up after running one of the two avd I have on my system but there is no way I can make it display my flutter project of which I think I need the run button to be able to effect such]

[image: As you can see in this image, i am not able to click the run button to run the flutter project on the virtual device.]

[image: This are the sdk's available on my android studio]

[image: These are the available android installed sdk platform]

Comment: First try to resolve the errors
Switch to beta channel and update the sdk and ndk

Comment: @Lathesh what errors please.

Answer (score 0):

Below reasons might disable the run button.

1. Build failure
2. Configurations beside the run button might have changed.
3. Recently same issue is being observed in Android studio.

Sometimes closing and reopening the project or android studio solves issues if there is no issue in building the project.

Comment: how do i fix the build failure then please. and also the configuration beside the run button. I have configured it to use the current project and the android directory to be specific.

Comment: @king_bibah By solving some errors in Proj,build failure can be resolved and even configuration will be resolved once the build is successful. But sorry,I am not aware of flutter to solve issue by seeing error.